# Android Room - получить данные из запроса с JOIN

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Есть такие Entity (Магазин и Чек):

**Shops**

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"inn"}, unique = true)})
public class Shops {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String inn;
}
```

**Receipts**

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
            entity = Shops.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "shop_id")
        )
public class Receipts {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public Long date;
    public double totalSum;
    public int shop_id;
}
```

Нужно получить список `Receipts`, в котором `shop_id` будет заменено на `Shops.name`. Т.е. выполнить объединение таблиц.

Из

[image: Source]

Получить

[image: Destination]

На чистом SQLite запрос был бы такой:

```
SELECT Receipts.id, Receipts.date, Receipts.totalSum, Shops.name
FROM Receipts
INNER JOIN Shops ON Shops.id = Receipts.shop_id;
```

Т.е. Dao вида:

```
@Query("SELECT Receipts.id, Receipts.date, Receipts.totalSum, Shops.name " +
            "FROM Receipts " +
            "INNER JOIN Shops ON Shops.id = Receipts.shop_id;")
public List<Receipts> getReceiptsWithShops();
```

Однако `List<Receipts>` не подходит в качестве возвращаемого типа данных.

Как лучше действовать при реализации через Room? Создавать новый класс Receipts?

Comment: Создать новый класс `ReceiptWithShop`. Документация по [Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html)